# Don't preserve state restoration for an UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application what is a web wrapper, I want when user open application and this became active the `UIWebView` to load always initial url and not last page from navigation of wrapper. I managed this but for some seconds the webview displayed old state of `UIWebView`. How can avoid this?
I tried in delegate of application to delete cookies and reload `UIWebView`

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
     [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [self.webWrapper.viewWeb reload];
}
```

but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just resetting completely the webview using something like this

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
```

and loading your initial url once the app became active?

Comment: yes, this solution is more elegant but the problem with old state remain. it's possible to avoid this delay for old webview?